# [iotivity]Need help using the javascript API

Tags: javascript, iotivity

i am using these codes:

Client.js:

```
var client = require('./Client');
client.on("resourcefound",function(event){
    //client.retrieve();
    //client.update();
});
client.findResources();
```

Server.js:

```
var server=require('./Server');

server.register({
    resourcePath:"/a/fan",
    resourceTypes:[ "core.fan" ],
    interfaces:["oic.if.baseline"],
    discoverable: true,
    properties:{on:false}
});
```

I am running these codes and nothing happened like a infinite loop in both terminals.

I am using Sakari's code and i get a lot of errors

Can anyone help me to understand if client discovers the resource and what can i do to see the request and response.

PS:i dont know if require is correct Sakari says require("oic")("client") for the client.js but i get error like oic not found.

Comment: Sakari poussa presentation: http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/NodeJS_JavaScript-for-IoTivity.pdf.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code - include your code as text here.

Comment: ohh i am sorry i didnt know that!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a more recent version of the iotivity-node.
IoTivity 1.3.0 has been released and it should now be supported by the recent version of iotivity-node.

Please use the latest code and let me know if you still face the issues.

refer to the client and server code under the following path.

js/high-level-client-example.js js/high-level-server-example.js